# Is Allow third party cookies setting need to be enabled to be able to read 3rd party cookies?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, setcookie

I am trying to read a 3rd party domain generated by the 3rd party (i.e. another host which is different from the UI) on the client-side.

So, this cookie has the Domain set explicitly to myuihost and also has SameSite=None and Secure flag set to true.

However, I am still unable to read the cookie.
Is Allow third party cookies setting in Chrome browser needed to be enabled to be able to read this 3rd party cookies ?

Comment: If you mean read them from `document.cookie` using javascript you can only access same domain cookies

Comment: You can't access cookies from another domain for obvious security reasons, allowing 3rd party cookies, as is currently the default doesn't change that either.  Basically 3rd party cookies work were the Javascript is loaded from, so if you wanted to access cookies from another domain, you would have to have your Javascript on there domain too.

Comment: @Keith - Thanks. For 3rd party cookies, when you say we need to have Javascript on the other domain too, could you please elaborate on the same...In this case though, the cookie is generated at server-side by another host...So I assume, if it cookie is generated on external/3rd party server, it is not possible to read at all (irrespective of the Allow third party cookies Chrome setting) ?

Comment: Correct!, eg.  if you had Facebook embedded on you web-page, the reason it knows who you are is because Facebook has the cookie for you stored on it's server, the Javascript that is then run is loaded from  Facebook server (3rd party cookie) so it can access the these cookies.  You can't however have Javascript loaded from your webserver that then could access Facebooks cookies.  Also worth noting, 3rd party cookies are set to be removed as default in 2023, so without user interaction these sites will fail.  I assume they will make it easier to enable with a popup, like allow microphone etc